# Is Sharepoint Designer 2013 compatible with Visio 2016?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow, 2016, visio

Is Sharepoint Designer 2013 compatible with Visio 2016?

I want to export a Workflow designed in SharePoint Designer 2013.

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1):

As a short answer, No,

> To export to Visio, you need to use the version of Visio Professional
>   that matches the version of SharePoint Designer that you're using.

So in your case, you should have Visio 2013 to can export a Workflow designed in SharePoint Designer 2013.

Answer (score -1):

The issue mentioned here and in other threads are already a year old, and I was wondering if there was by now, perhaps a permanent solution like a patch by Microsoft?

I have a new laptop with Office2016 and I just realized that SPD2013 does not work with Visio2016.

Anyway, I cannot imagine that Microsoft would still advise (after the issue was communicated a year ago) to downgrade Visio to 2013 version.
 What is the workaround, patch or solution by Microsoft?

I am not keen to de-install Office2016 and downgrade, or get an older laptop with Office2013.

(Installing older Office versions on my new laptop with Office2016 is unfortunately not possible due to Company IT policies)

I hope Microsoft has a solution for this seriously frustrating problem.